# spacy NLP how to extract information this case

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

Please take a look at this case.
I want to extract intent from this sentence with Spacy, NLP Python

```
noun -> gaming
adj -> super perfect

noun -> everyday use
adj -> super perfect
```

Information of this sentence

```
this is super perfect for gaming and everyday use

this (DET) nsubj is
is (AUX) ROOT is
super (ADV) advmod perfect
perfect (ADJ) acomp is
for (ADP) prep perfect
gaming (NOUN) pobj for
and (CCONJ) cc gaming
everyday (ADJ) advmod use
use (NOUN) conj gaming
```

I tried with

```
noun= "NOUN"
adj = "ADJ"

for token in doc:    
    add_neg_pfx = False
    if(token.dep_ == "pobj"):
        noun+= token.text

    if(token.dep_ == "prep"):
        adj += token.head.text
```

But this code seem not as aspected

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: hmm, i started learning spacy for a week but not really understand logic to get adj "super perfect" first before noun "gaming" / "everyday use"

Comment: dspencer: comment updated with my try